# OpenCV detect-multi-scale confusion

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, downsampling

I am using OpenCV's detect multi-scale. I do not understand however, whether the `scale0` parameter refers to a *downscale* or an *upscale* factor. (Or both?). The documentation is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html).

The documentation says that the `scale0` parameter refers to the co-efficient of the window increase. Does this then mean that the image is only ever *downsampled*, for `nLevels`?

Thank you.

Comment: From my experience I think you are right, the image is always downsampled (or the detection size is upsampled). I think thats because the trained detectors are typically quite small.

Comment: Thanks @Micka. It seems that they never *upsample* the *image* though, which ... I am not sure why not...

Comment: I dont know, but as I said it might be that standard training is done on "minimal" detector size (dimensions like 64x64) so that upsampling the image might be very costly and inefficient. If you have an educated guess about an area where a smaller object might be you can still upscale the whole image or just that area manually. If you always want to upscale, just do it manually too